# Loop through a Firebase Snapshot and get values using PHP

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been trying to find documentation about this question but so far without luck. This is what I have:

```
$firebase = (new Factory)
->withServiceAccount($serviceAccount)
->withDatabaseUri('https://mydomain.firebaseio.com/')
->create();

$db = $firebase->getDatabase();

$db->getReference('cars')
->orderByChild('brand')
->equalTo('volvo')
->limitToLast(10)
->getSnapshot();

...
```

Now, how do I loop through the data and get the values from the snapshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to get the values from the snapshot/reference:

```
$firebase = (new Factory)
->withServiceAccount($serviceAccount)
->withDatabaseUri('https://mydomain.firebaseio.com/')
->create();

$db = $firebase->getDatabase();

$ref->getReference('cars')->orderByChild('brand')->equalTo('volvo')->limitToLast(10);

$values = $ref->getValue();

...
```